# How to delete the rows in pandas where all the column values are null except first three columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame like this:

```
df
col1   col2   col3   col4   col5    col6
 1      2       NA    3      NA      NA
 4      5       6     7      NA      NA
 8      9       NA    NA     NA      NA
 10     11      NA    NA     NA      NA
 13     14      15    NA     16      17
```

There is no NA values for col1 and col2, I want to remove those rows where all the values from col3 to col6 (can be col100 and so on) are NA.

I can do this using following code,

```
 df[(df.col3.notnull)&(df.col4.notnull)&(df.col5.notnull)&(df.col6.notnull)]
```

But if the number of columns increases, this task is not a good idea, writing all the columns names inside,

The result I am looking for is,

```
df
col1   col2   col3   col4   col5    col6
 1      2       NA    3      NA      NA
 4      5       6     7      NA      NA
 13     14      15    NA     16      17
```

Is there any pandas tricks to do it in most efficient way ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way `dropna` with `thresh` : 3 valid values per row

```
df.dropna(thresh=3)
Out[254]: 
   col1  col2  col3  col4  col5  col6
0     1     2   NaN   3.0   NaN   NaN
1     4     5   6.0   7.0   NaN   NaN
4    13    14  15.0   NaN  16.0  17.0
```

Comment: This will count `NaN` in the first three columns as well.

Comment: @QuangHoang *There is no NA values for col1 and col2*

Comment: Ah, sorry, I did miss that part.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to ignore `col1` and `col2` and check if `all(axis=1)` applies

```
df.drop(['col1', 'col2'],1).isnull().all(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is calculate sum and filter not equal to `0`:

```
df[df.iloc[:,2:].sum(1).ne(0)]
```

---

```
   col1  col2  col3  col4  col5  col6
0     1     2   NaN   3.0   NaN   NaN
1     4     5   6.0   7.0   NaN   NaN
4    13    14  15.0   NaN  16.0  17.0
```